# Tomcat Not Accepting Username/Password for Manager GUI

Tags: tomcat, jsp

Tomcat 7 on Arch Linux. Was working before but I screwed it up so this is now a fresh install (removed package, dependencies, cleaned cache, rebooted, reinstalled, restarted). I try to log in to the Manager GUI but it keeps prompting me for my username and password even when I enter correctly. Thought it might be permissions so I `chown`'d everything to `tomcat:tomcat` but still nothing.

Here's my `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="[CHANGE_ME]" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="manager" password="[CHANGE_ME]" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
  <user username="admin" password="[CHANGE_ME]" roles="admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: how did you fix it, I have the same issue, <role rolename="manager"/> <role rolename="manager-gui"/> <role rolename="admin"/> < <role rolename="admin-gui"/> <user username="shehab" password="test123" roles="admin,admin-gui,manager,manager-gui"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I'm an idiot. Malformed `tomcat-users.xml` due to hastily copy-and-pasting tutorial example.